# PHP class implementation

Tags: php, oop

I need a little bit of help understanding PHP Classes.
I'm ok with the code but its more the implementation, what to contain in a class, that I'm struggling to get to grips with.

Using a blog as an example site, on the homepage (or posts page) I'm going to have a list of multiple posts.

Would I:

A: Create a class to get the details for a single post and call that within a loop on index page.

B: Create a class that gets and returns all the posts for the page and each indivdual posts details within the same class.

C: Create a class to get the list of post for the page and a seperate class to get the indiviudal post details.

My gut is telling me its C, so I can reuse the individual post class on other parts of the site (ie individual post page) and resue the class to get all the post in other ways (maybe for feature posts or similar).

Any tips welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is far too broad. I suggest you try doing any elementary PHP OOP tutorial first, to get the basics of what for (and how) OOP helps

Comment: For this case you may need only one class with two method. first method to get the list and second method to get the details.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, one class should do. No need for Multiple Classes that does essentially the same thing (with a very slight alteration). Consider the Empty Class below:

```
<?php


    class Post{
        protected $post;
        protected $lastPost;

        const   POST_TYPE_SINGLE    = 1;
        const   POST_TYPE_LIST      = 2;

        public function getPostList(){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET ALL THE POSTS EXISTING WITHIN YOUR SYSTEM...
            // NO HTML RENDERING...
        }

        public function getPostByID($postID){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET RAW DATA FOR THE POST WITH THE ID $postID
            // NO HTML RENDERING...
        }

        public function getDetailedView($post){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET ONE SINGLE POST AS A HTML RENDER USING THE $post...
        }

        public function getListView($posts){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET ALLS POSTS AS A HTML RENDER USING THE $posts...
        }

        public function getPostsByDate($date) {
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET ALL THE POSTS POSTED ON THE SAME DATE: $date..

        }

        public function getPostByAuthor($author){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO GET ALL THE POSTS POSTED BY THE SAME AUTHOR: $author...

        }

        public function render($post, $postType=1){
            // IMPLEMENTATION CODE
            // TO RENDER THE POST AS HTML STRING TO BE DISPLAYED AT THE FRONT-END...
            // COULD BE USED TO RENDER BOTH DETAILED AND LIST VIEWS DEPENDING ON
            // THE VALUE OF $postType...
            if($postType == self::POST_TYPE_SINGLE){
                // CODE FOR HTML SINGLE POST RENDER
            }else{
                // CODE FOR HTML LIST-VIEW RENDER                   
            }               
        }

    }
```